# Virus defender выбивает, что это вредоносная программа, что делать? (фото прикреплено)

Tags: windows

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сколько не удалял папку RobotDemo ничего не помогало. Пишу тут, тк. нету больше выбора. Virus Defender регулярно присылает сообщение о том, что это вирус.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в действия и выберите нужные. Windows Defender не очень хороший анти вирус по своему использованию, лично я советую вам установить другой. (Если ничего не помогает отключите его)

Comment: А можно уточнить, какие именно "нужные" действия?

Comment: Выберите действия по удалению и т.д